# Make a div visible for a certain time when hovered on list items

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a category list. When a list item is hovered over, a div (#category-menu) gets visible containing some items. But my problem is that div becomes invisible immediately mouse leaves the list item. I want this div to remain visible until mouse leaves it or stay visible for a certain time.

Please look at the Code and Snippet :

```js
$('#category .list-group-item').hover(function(){
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 $('#category-menu').toggleClass('invisible visible');
 $('#category-menu .row').each(function(){
  var rowid = $(this).attr('id');
  if(rowid == id){
   $('#category-menu .row').hide();
   $(this).toggleClass('invisible visible').show();
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='category' class='container-fluid container-margin mt-sm-2'>
    <div class='row'>
     <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <div class="list-group">
        <a id='0' href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">LED TV Monitor</a>
        <a id='1' href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Sound System</a>
        <a id='2' href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Projector</a>
      </div>
     </div>

         <div class='col-sm-9'>       
         <div id='category-menu' class='bg-light invisible' style='z-index:99;position:absolute;width:60vw;min-height:30vw;margin-left:-2.5vw;'>
          <div id='0' class='row invisible'>
           <div class='col-sm-4'>
            <p><b>Dell LED Monitor</b></p>
           </div>
           <div class='col-sm-4'>
            <p><b>Skyview LED Monitor</b></p>
           </div>
           <div class='col-sm-4'>
            <p><b>Circle LED Monitor</b></p>
           </div>    
          </div>
          
          <div id='1' class='row invisible'>
           <div class='col-sm-4'>
            <p><b>Home Threatre</b></p>
           </div>
           <div class='col-sm-4'>
            <p><b>Sound System</b></p>
           </div>
           <div class='col-sm-4'>
            <p><b>Sound System</b></p>
           </div>    
          </div>
               
          <div id='2' class='row invisible'>
           <div class='col-sm-4'>
            <p><b>Phillips</b></p>
           </div>
           <div class='col-sm-4'>
            <p><b>Epson</b></p>
           </div>
           <div class='col-sm-4'>
            <p><b>Toshiba</b></p>
           </div>
          </div>
        
         </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

If you have seen the snippet you noticed that `#category-menu` hides immediately after mouse out. I want it to stay visible so that user can choose items from it. And then make invisible when mouse leaves the `#category-menu`.

Comment: Id should be unique in a page. You can prefix them with some chars like `d0,` `d1`...

Comment: Try replacing *hover(...)* with *mouseenter(...)*.

Comment: @Priyesh Kumar, will make that change... but I think that's not an issue here....

Comment: @AedvaldTseh, tried mouseenter() and mouseleave() with no good luck....

Comment: have you used delay ??

Comment: @melvin, can you please show me a way to add delay...

Comment: @Aedvald Tseh, I am very much familiar with w3schools.... My situation is a bit complicated here... I have to catch an ID and compare it with group of items.... couldn't properly fit delay()....